# (Cocos2d-x) Is there any action can blur a Sprite?

Tags: opengl, textures, cocos2d-x

I add a Sprite as background.
Now I wish my Sprite can blur gradually become blurred.

I think I may modify the Texture2D to do the job, but it seems that Texture2D can not be modified.

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use shader for that. You can get simple blur shader from cocos test project, like this:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float blurRadius;
uniform float sampleNum;

vec4 blur(vec2);

void main(void)
{
vec4 col = blur(v_texCoord); //* v_fragmentColor.rgb;
gl_FragColor = vec4(col) * v_fragmentColor;
}

vec4 blur(vec2 p)
{
    if (blurRadius > 0.0 && sampleNum > 1.0)
    {
        vec4 col = vec4(0);
        vec2 unit = 1.0 / resolution.xy;

        float r = blurRadius;
        float sampleStep = r / sampleNum;

        float count = 0.0;

        for(float x = -r; x < r; x += sampleStep)
        {
            for(float y = -r; y < r; y += sampleStep)
            {
                float weight = (r - abs(x)) * (r - abs(y));
                col += texture2D(CC_Texture0, p + vec2(x * unit.x, y * unit.y)) * weight;
                count += weight;
            }
        }

        return col / count;
    }

    return texture2D(CC_Texture0, p);
}
```

If you don't know how to add custom shader to your sprite - here is an example!
You extend Sprite class:

```
class MySpriteBlur : public Sprite {
public:
    ~MySpriteBlur();
    bool initWithTexture(Texture2D* texture, const Rect&  rect);
    void initGLProgram();
    static MySpriteBlur *create(const char *pszFileName);
    void setBlurRadius(float radius);
    void setBlurSampleNum(float num);
protected:
    float _blurRadius;
    float _blurSampleNum;
};
```

And then implement it:

```
MySpriteBlur::~MySpriteBlur() {
}
MySpriteBlur* MySpriteBlur::create(const char *pszFileName) {
    MySpriteBlur* pRet = new (std::nothrow) MySpriteBlur();
    if (pRet && pRet->initWithFile(pszFileName)) {
        pRet->autorelease();
    } else {
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(pRet);
    }
    return pRet;
}
bool MySpriteBlur::initWithTexture(Texture2D* texture, const Rect& rect) {
    _blurRadius = 0;
    if (Sprite::initWithTexture(texture, rect)) {
#if CC_ENABLE_CACHE_TEXTURE_DATA
        auto listener = EventListenerCustom::create(EVENT_RENDERER_RECREATED, [this](EventCustom* event) {
            initGLProgram();
        });
        _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
#endif
        initGLProgram();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void MySpriteBlur::initGLProgram() {
    std::string fragSource = FileUtils::getInstance()->getStringFromFile(
        FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("shaders/example_blur.fsh"));
    auto program = GLProgram::createWithByteArrays(ccPositionTextureColor_noMVP_vert, fragSource.data());
    auto glProgramState = GLProgramState::getOrCreateWithGLProgram(program);
    setGLProgramState(glProgramState);
    auto size = getTexture()->getContentSizeInPixels();
    getGLProgramState()->setUniformVec2("resolution", size);
    getGLProgramState()->setUniformFloat("blurRadius", _blurRadius);
    getGLProgramState()->setUniformFloat("sampleNum", 7.0f);
}
void MySpriteBlur::setBlurRadius(float radius) {
    _blurRadius = radius;
    getGLProgramState()->setUniformFloat("blurRadius", _blurRadius);
}
void MySpriteBlur::setBlurSampleNum(float num) {
    _blurSampleNum = num;
    getGLProgramState()->setUniformFloat("sampleNum", _blurSampleNum);
}
```

Hope that will help!

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1) make a blurred background in photoshop (quick and simple, but extra size),

2) use a shader (not that simple and blur is a heavy operation),

3) redraw (on the fly) your background making it a new texture.
Here's my post how to draw on texture:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/is-it-possible-to-erase-some-pixels-from-a-sprite/34460/5?u=piotrros

Knowing this here's a function from my project, which blurs one image (a data array) to another one:

```
void Sample::blur(unsigned char* inputData, unsigned char* outputData, float r) {
    int R2 = pow(r + 2, 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < canvasHeight; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < canvasWidth; j++) {
            int val1 = 0;
            int val2 = 0;
            int val3 = 0;
            int val4 = 0;

            int index2 = (j + (canvasHeight - i - 1) * canvasWidth) * 4;

            for(int iy = i - r; iy < i + r + 1; iy++){
                for(int ix = j - r; ix < j + r + 1; ix++) {

                    int x = CLAMP(ix, 0, canvasWidth - 1);
                    int y = CLAMP(iy, 0, canvasHeight - 1);

                    int index = (x + (canvasHeight - y - 1) * canvasWidth) * 4;

                    val1 += inputData[index];
                    val2 += inputData[index + 1];
                    val3 += inputData[index + 2];
                    val4 += inputData[index + 3];
                }
            }

            outputData[index2] = val1 / R2;
            outputData[index2 + 1] = val2 / R2;
            outputData[index2 + 2] = val3 / R2;
            outputData[index2 + 3] = val4 / R2;
        }
    }
}
```

Just remember that blur is heavy and long operation so if you have a big image it may take a while.